# Node and multiple function calls from a single route, returning calculated data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mean-stack

I am making a single API call to a route (MEAN stack) to populate a chart.js graph on the front end. The API call needs to return year-to-date, month-to-date, and historical data (year-to-date last year, month-to-date last year, etc.). The functional programming best practices I'm trying to follow are making this a mess; is there a better way?

Here is the template I am filling in so far:

```
router.post('/sales_chart', (req, res, next)=>{
    const store = req.body.store;
    const date = req.body.date;

    dailySalesModel.getSalesYTD (store, date, (err, daily_data)=>{
        if(err) logger.error(err);
        if(!daily_data) {
            return res.json({success: false, message: 'No daily sales data found'});
        }
        let sales = [];
        // **calculate sales year-to-date**

        // Fetch the same data from one year earlier.
        dailySalesModel.getSales (store, SAME_DAY_LAST_YEAR, (err, last_year_daily_data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!last_year_daily_data) {
                return res.json({success: false, message: 'No last year daily sales data found'});
            }

            let last_year_sales = [];
            // **calculate sales year-to-date**

            dailySalesModel.getSalesMTD (store, date, (err, mtd_data) => {
                if(err) logger.error(err);
                if(!mtd_data) {
                    return res.json({success: false, message: 'No MTD sales data found'});
                }
                let mtd_sales = [];
                // **calculate sales month-to-date**

                // Fetch the same data from one year earlier.
                dailySalesModel.getSalesMTD(store, SAME_DAY_LAST_YEAR, (err, last_year_mtd_data) => {
                    if(err) logger.error(err);
                    if(!last_year_mtd_data) {
                        return res.json({success: false, message: 'No last year MTD sales data found'});
                    }
                    let last_year_mtd_sales = [];
                    // **calculate sales month-to-date**

                    // and so on... 
                    dailySalesModel.getEvenMoreHistoricalData(...)
                        ...


                })
            });

            return res.json({success: true, sales_data: { sales: sales, 
                                                          last_year_sales: last_year_sales, 
                                                          mtd_sales: mtd_sales, 
                                                          last_year_mtd_sales, mtd_last_year_sales, 
                                                          date: date } });
        });
    })
});
```

...and I'm starting to feel like all the 'nested' functions are not necessary and there must be a better way to do this. For example, I don't think this handles cases where some function calls return null or empty data (maybe a new store wasn't open last year on the specified date) but I want to keep fetching the rest of the data for return.

Is there a better way to make several calls and return all the calculated data as a single JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your `dailySalesModel` methods as promises? That would save you from callback hell a little bit.

Another thing you can do is separate each of these into middlwares. A middleware in express is just a function that runs in between when the request is made and the response is sent. So, for example, you might have a `middlewares.js` file:

```
function getSalesYTD(req, res, next) {
  const { store, date } = req.body
  dailySalesModel.getSalesYTD(store, date, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return next(err)
    res.locals.daily_data = result
    next()
  })
}

function getSales(req, res, next) {
  // etc
  // access daily_data on res.locals.daily_data
}
```

(If you haven't run into `res.locals` before, it's just a property on the response object that's there for you to store stuff in during one request/response cycle. It's there for the duration of the cycle and is cleared out for each new request.)

And then in your route, just chain them all along:

```
const { getSalesYTD, getSales, otherThings } = require('./middlewares')
router.post('/sales_chart', getSalesYTD, getSales, otherThings, (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    daily_data: res.locals.daily_data
    // etc
  })
})
```

Is this the type of thing you're hoping to accomplish?

The other benefit of doing it like this is that if you need to make one of those requests in a different route, you don't have to write it out again -- you can just use the same middleware, provided you remember where on `res.locals` you put the data.

[Here's an example of a route that uses this pattern.](https://github.com/jlr7245/flashcards/blob/master/routes/flashcards-routes.js#L40)